# Cocos2d animation from sprite sheet

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, cocos2d-iphone

So i have the action build to make my frog jump but i have 5 images and i want to run them in the order 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1 using the coordinates. I only want to loop them once everytime the from jumps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while defining your image you can use the following code:

```
CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"frog"];
CCSpriteFrame* frames[5];
CGRect Rect;
// some code to initialize Rect position
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    frames[i] = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:@"frog.png" rect:Rect];
    // some code to move Rect so that it will mark next frame;
}
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    [anim addFrame:frames[i]];
for(int i=3;i>=0;i--)
    [anim addFrame:frames[i]];
```

Comment: I am REALLY new to cocos2d, this is my first project on it.                How do i declare CCAnimation, CCSpriteFrame, anime, etc?

Comment: tha's just a tricky question! all i did was include cocos2d.h and i had access to everything i needed! and by the way i made miskate writing anime i just meant anim as i edited above

Comment: you can also follow [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d) it shows the whole process of playing an animation in cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

use ccanimation and ccspritebatchnodefile

save your image sequence in spritesheet